# Replace words in an unstructured text file using a for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a VERY unstructured text file that I read with readLines. I want to change certain strings to another string which is in a variable (called "new" below).

Below I want the manipulated text to include all terms: "one", "two", "three" and "four" once, instead of the "change" strings. However, as you can see sub changes the first pattern in each element, but I need the code to ignore that there are new strings with quotes.

See example code and data below.

```
 #text to be changed
 text <- c("TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT change",
        "TEXT TEXT TEXT change TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT change", 
        "TEXT TEXT TEXT change TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT")

 #Variable containing input for text
 new <- c("one", "two", "three", "four")
 #For loop that I want to include 
 for (i in 1:length(new)) {

   text  <- sub(pattern = "change", replace = new[i], x = text)

 }
 text
```

Comment: Are you need

 text <- c("TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT one",
        "TEXT TEXT TEXT two TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT three", 
        "TEXT TEXT TEXT four TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT") 
as a result?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this? The logic is, hammer away a string until it has no more `change`. On every "hit" (where `change` is found), move along the `new` vector.

```
text <- c("TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT change",
          "TEXT TEXT TEXT change TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT change", 
          "TEXT TEXT TEXT change TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT")

#Variable containing input for text
new <- c("one", "two", "three", "four")
new.i <- 1

for (i in 1:length(text)) {
  while (grepl(pattern = "change", text[i])) {
    text[i] <- sub(pattern = "change", replacement = new[new.i], x = text[i])
    new.i <- new.i + 1
  }
}
text

[1] "TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT one" 
[2] "TEXT TEXT TEXT two TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT three"
[3] "TEXT TEXT TEXT four TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution using `gregexpr()` and `regmatches()`:

```r
#text to be changed
text <- c("TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT change",
          "TEXT TEXT TEXT change TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT change",
          "TEXT TEXT TEXT change TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT")

#Variable containing input for text
new <- c("one", "two", "three", "four")

# Alter the structure of text
altered_text <- paste(text, collapse = "\n")

# So we can use gregexpr and regmatches to get what you want
matches <- gregexpr("change", altered_text)
regmatches(altered_text, matches) <- list(new)

# And here's the result
cat(altered_text)
#> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT one
#> TEXT TEXT TEXT two TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT three
#> TEXT TEXT TEXT four TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT

# Or, putting the text back to its old structure
# (one element for each line)
unlist(strsplit(altered_text, "\n"))
#> [1] "TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT one" 
#> [2] "TEXT TEXT TEXT two TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT three"
#> [3] "TEXT TEXT TEXT four TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT"
```

We can do this since `gregexpr()` can find all the matches in the text for "change"; from `help("gregexpr")`:

> regexpr returns an integer vector of the same length as text giving
>   the starting position of the first match....
>
> gregexpr returns a list of the same length as text each element of
>   which is of the same form as the return value for regexpr, except that
>   the starting positions of **every** (disjoint) match are given.

(emphasis added).

Then `regmatches()` can be used to either extract the matches found by `gregexpr()` **or replace them**; from `help("regmatches")`:

> Usage
>
> regmatches(x, m, invert = FALSE)
>   regmatches(x, m, invert = FALSE) <- value
>
> ...
>
> value
>   an object with suitable replacement values for the matched or
>   non-matched substrings (see Details).
>
> ...
>
> Details
>
> The replacement function can be used for replacing the matched or
>   non-matched substrings. For vector match data, if invert is FALSE,
>   value should be a character vector with length the number of matched
>   elements in m. Otherwise, it should be a list of character vectors
>   with the same length as m, each as long as the number of replacements
>   needed.

Comment: I like this approach. The only caveat that I see, which is why I did not go down a similar path with concatenation, is that there may be `\n` in some string, at which point things would hit the proverbial fan in the very last step.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `strsplit`:

```
tl <- lapply(text, function(s) strsplit(s, split = " ")[[1]])
df <- stack(setNames(tl, seq_along(tl)))

ix <- df$values == "change"
df[ix, "values"] <- new
tapply(df$values, df$ind, paste, collapse = " ")
```

which gives:

> ```
>                                                   1 
>  "TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT one" 
>                                                   2 
> "TEXT TEXT TEXT two TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT three" 
>                                                   3 
>           "TEXT TEXT TEXT four TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT"
> ```

Additionally you could wrap the `tapply` call in `unname`:

```
 unname(tapply(df$values, df$ind, paste, collapse = " "))
```

which gives:

> ```
> [1] "TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT one" 
> [2] "TEXT TEXT TEXT two TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT three"
> [3] "TEXT TEXT TEXT four TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT"
> ```

---

If you want to use the elements of `new` only once, you could update the code to:

```
newnew <- new[1:3]

ix <- df$values == "change"
df[ix, "values"][1:length(newnew)] <- newnew
unname(tapply(df$values, df$ind, paste, collapse = " "))
```

---

You could alter this further to also take into account the situation where there are more replacements than positions (occurences of the pattern, `change` in the example) that need to be replaced:

```
newnew2 <- c(new, "five")

tl <- lapply(text, function(s) strsplit(s, split = " ")[[1]])
df <- stack(setNames(tl, seq_along(tl)))

ix <- df$values == "change"
df[ix, "values"][1:pmin(sum(ix),length(newnew2))] <- newnew2[1:pmin(sum(ix),length(newnew2))]
unname(tapply(df$values, df$ind, paste, collapse = " "))
```